In VSCode - Saving with CMD + S doesn't work
Recently, I had an issue that using the CMD + S doesn't save the file in VSCODE.
I thought maybe it is a version issue, I upgraded to the latest version, but the issue still presist, also I checked the keyabord shortcut map CMD + S is mapped for save.
BTW, saving by clicking "Save" item in the File menu working fine, the same with enable Auto Save.

Not sure who down voted this issue. It is a valid issue and the solution suggested to close ChatGPT desktop app and reopen it worked for me. So upvoting both the question and the answer.

According to this thread, this issue is properly because of the ChatGPT desktop.
How to resolve

Upgrade to the latest version of ChatGPT desktop app.
If upgrading doesn't work, try just to quit the ChatGPT desktop app and re-open again.


As of the date of this comment this problem persists with the most up to date version. Re-opening ChatGPT fixed VSCode for me. Thank you.
